# Bing Maps: Removing shadow on Infobox in IE8

Tags: css, internet-explorer-8, filter, bing-maps

This tiny ammend i am trying to make is driving me nuts. Hopefully one of you guys have come across this issue before.

So i am using the 'Bing Maps Ajax Control 7.0 ISDK' and am trying to create my own custom Infobox (popup box) on hover of my pin.

All good apart from removing a box shadow on the Infobox in IE8. I have applied the following CSS to cancel any regular CSS shadow properties.

```
-moz-box-shadow: none !important;
-webkit-box-shadow: none !important;
box-shadow: none !important;
```

Which works in Chrome, Firefox etc. The issue is with IE8 where the Bing CSS file is adding this to the Infobox:

```
-ms-filter: "progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Shadow(Strength=4, Direction=135, Color='#888888')";
```

Now i have pretty much exhausted any methods of overriding this style. I have added to my own stylesheets, tried using a background image instead, tried adding an override in the JS for my maps functionality by adding it directly to my html for the 'htmlcontent' param in the Infobox options object. No luck.

Anyone know how I can remove this shadow?

thanks
Craig

Answer (score 1):

to be honest trying to override the default infobox is dangerous and not recommended because bing could change the infobox's css class or ids tomorrow and you hack would stop working. I recommend you look at the custom infobox control here, its better anyway and then you have complete control:

http://bingmapsv7modules.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=Custom%20Infobox%20Control

Comment: Hey guys,

This might help out some of you guys working with Bing Maps, but i have finally stumbled across the solution!

It seems that if you simply alter the the class of the Infobox in your js to anything other than Infobox, a lot of the default CSS gets removed! And with that, the horrible shadows i was getting.

Something to remember when customising your Infoboxes!!

cheers People,

Comment: @BarberCraig if your anwer worked and is your accepted solution to the problem please post it as an actual answer and not a comment to one.